# Forbid any combination of values after the first one in mysql

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I have a relation table in Mysql with 3 columns

1. ID (Primary key and Auto Increment)
2. Ref_id1 (Reference ID from table1)
3. Ref_id2 (Reference ID from table1 also)

How can i forbid, in database level, any pair combination of Ref_id1 and Ref_id2 from reappearing.

**EDIT:**

For example: 
After i insert a row like this

`id    Ref_id1    Ref_id2 
 1        1          2`

i want to forbid ANY other row with the same pair of Ref_id1 and Ref_id2 (which a UNIQUE INDEX can solve)
AND any row with the reversed pair

`Ref_id1    Ref_id2 
    2          1`

PS. Sorry for the ugly coding, i'm new to the community and i can't use the tools correctly

**EDIT 2:**

My question is different from the duplicate proposed because i want to be able to restrict BOTH insertions

Pair1:

`Ref_id1   Ref_id2
    1         2`

AND

Pair2:

`Ref_id1   Ref_id2
    2         1`

AFTER my original insertion.

**EDIT 3:**

If this helps at all:
Both Ref_id1 and Ref_id2 are foreign keys from the same column of a foreign table

Comment: Just use a [composite unique index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html).

Comment: True but i think that this solves only half of my problem.

Comment: And you can solve the other half by creating a second unique index.

Comment: Could you enforce at the application level that ref1 < ref2? That would allow you to use a unique index as @BoristheSpider suggests

Comment: Unfortunately no. I want to be able to store a pair in any way i want.

Answer (score 0):

You want a `unique key` constraint.

In your Create Table syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table(
  id bigint(20) primary key auto_increment,
  ref_id1 bigint(20) not null,
  ref_id2 bigint(20) not null,
  unique key `ref_uniqueness` (ref_id1, ref_id2)
)
```

Or, if your table already exists, use `alter table`:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
ADD UNIQUE CONSTRAINT `ref_uniqueness` (ref_id1, ref_id2)
```

Comment: Is this going to solve both problems?

Comment: It doesn't work. I already had my table created so i used the second suggestion in MySQL workbench and it has syntax error near CONSTRAINT